# Arch Linux Matlab Command Window creation failed

Tags: arch-linux, matlab

I just changed a font in my matlab and when I reopened it, it crashes. I ran Matlab on steam deck, an arch linux based system. The following is the log.

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /home/deck/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: radeonsi
MESA-LOADER: failed to open kms_swrast: /home/deck/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: kms_swrast
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/deck/matlab/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load swrast driver
Gtk-Message: 23:26:44.587: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Answer (score 0):

These are several bugs, which need different solutions.
On Gentoo Linux I had also the GLIBCXX_3.4.29 problem.
With the following workaround one can help MATLAB to find the file

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.2.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.30 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2022a/bin/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
```

You have to adjust the directories to your version/system.

Lets solve the second part about `Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"` in a separate question:
[MATLAB Warning: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716485/matlab-warning-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module)

See also:

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Matlab
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MATLAB